# Connecting to Google Talk on tablet

Tags: tablet, google-talk

I am trying to connect to Google Talk on my Android tablet. The error message is saying 'the connection interrupted'. The tablet has connected to Wi-fi and I can browse the Internet. I am using version 4.0 OS.

What might be stopping it from connecting to Google Talk?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a too restrictive firewall, either in your WiFi router or your tablet. Try opening up the ports that GTalk needs and check that access to GTalk servers isn't blocked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to Google Servers over your wifi connection the wifi bars in the status bar should be blue. If they bars are gray then you are not connected to the Google Servers.

I have run into this issue on open wi-fi and on some corporate wi-fi networks with a firewall. The only solution I've found is to use a third party app like [Trillian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ceruleanstudios.trillian.android&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd). I can use Trillian (with my GTalk account) to GTalk when I'm not connected to the Google Servers.